# How to intercept android app launch (without using main Activity's onCreate event)

Tags: android

I need to execute some code whenever my android application is launched, so that i can initialize my mainActivity menu. The menu should be initialized only when the app is started and should remember the menu item selected, for example when i return to the mainActivity from other childs Activies (i.e. after pressing the back or Up Button).

I already tried to use onCreate event, sharedPreference and getIntent() function but they aren't good for that pourpose. I need something analogue to onLoad() HTML pages event. Any help?

1) OnCreate is called any time the device is rotated, the keyboard is opened, or you switch apps and the system decides it's time to reclaim some memory and kill off your app. And OnCreate is not tied to the app lyfecycle but only Activity Lifecycle. It is also called when you get back to the main activity using the "Up" button if you don't use android:launchmode=singleTop in the manifest. Yes you could store your previous state... end restore it on onResume, but it seems so tricky and not natural.

2) getIntent() return the same action whenever i return to the main Activity from other childs activities (in some circumstances).

3) i can use sharedPreference to store a value permanently, but then, when i relaunch the app the value has the last value that is setted and i can't know that way if the app is just launched or not.

If you don't agree with that sentences please provide me an example to prove i am wrong. I tried lots of solutions.

Comment: `they aren't good for that pourpose` they are good. You just likely misuse them.

Comment: what is your problem with onCreate? Do not really understand your problem - perhaps onResume is what you are looking for?

Comment: onCreate is execute everytime i return to the mainactivity from other activities, so i can't really know when it is executed on its first app launch.

Comment: "OnCreate is always called evrytime i return to the mainActivities from other child activities" -- no, it is not, unless you are doing something *very* strange in your code.

Comment: You're completely wrong about onCreate.  But even if you were right-  make a boolean variable in the MainActivity class isInitialized.  Defaults to false.  in onCreate, check if its false, if so initialize and set it to true.  If not, do nothing.

Comment: Moreover OnCreate is called any time the device is rotated, the keyboard is opened, or you switch apps and the system decides it's time to reclaim some memory and kill off your app. And OnCreate is not tied to the app lyfecycle but only Activity Lifecycle. So it is completely wrong to put code there for the porpouse i need. I need a variable that has the app scope not the activity scope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll try to give a complete answer. 
If you just need to execute some code when your app starts, then you can create your custom Application class. You can do it like this:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        //Here you can put your startup logic
    }
}
```

Then, you'll have to modify the  tag in your manifest.xml file. You'll need to tell it that the application must be the one you defined, and you can do it like this:

```
<application
    android:name=".MyApplication"
    ...
    >
```

Obviously, I am assuming your MyApplication class is on the base package of your application.

However, from what I am reading in your post, you need something different from this. You can't set your UI from Application, because there is no UI yet, and the UI is something that only an Activity (and its children, of course) can own. I would instead investigate further on what you are doing inside your onCreate method. Are you setting the selected menu item everytime onCreate is being called? If so, you could just write the actual selected menu item in your shared preferences. You can update this value everytime a different menu item is selected, then, in your onCreate, you just have to read this value from shared preferences and select the saved item, not just the "default one".

Comment: Yes i could use SharedPreference to store the selected menu item , and i did it , but when i restart the app I don't want the last selected menu item, i want to set it back to the first item of the menu.

Comment: I could use the inherited application class to store a property that i can set it back to false when the UI is created.... for example: MyApplication.OnCreate() { set appstarted=true}, then in onCreate of the mainactivity : if (MyApplication.appstart=true) appstart=false; ... something like this...

Comment: Yep, that's a great option! It could work. Or, since you've already used shared prefs, you can write back your default value in the prefs inside the onCreate method of your MyApplication. This will ensure that you won't use a strong reference inside the Application class

Comment: I am going to try it this evening and i will let you know if it works...

Answer (score 1):

This my example:

```
public class MainApplication extends Application {

    private static Resources mResources;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        mResources = this.getApplicationContext().getResources();
    }

    public static String getStringResource(int resId) {
        return mResources.getString(resId);
    }
}
```

Don't forget to add this new application in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.android.example">

    <application

        android:name=".MainApplication"

        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

And finally you can use that initialization like so:

```
public class DetailModel {
  private String title;

  public DetailModel(boolean aFlag) {
    if(aFlag) {
      title = movieData.getTitle();
    } else {
      title = MainApplication.getStringResource(R.string.default_title);
    }
  }

  public String getTitle() {
    return title;
  }

  public void setTitle(String t) {
    this.title = t;
  }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: i can add this link that helped me a lot too : https://androidexample.com/Global_Variable_Or_Application_Context_Variable_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=114&aaid=136